# allocate libname saspy python SASmagic command

Tags: python, sas, sas-macro, saspy

While using SaSPy, how can I find where the library RWORK is located ? 
I tried sas.dirlist() but without being able to find anything.
It might be due to remote access?

Below is my setup connexion

```
import saspy
import pandas as pd
import sas_kernel
import saspy.sascfg

# connexion 
sas = saspy.SASsession(cfgfile='C:\\Users\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\sascfg.py', cfgname='iomcom',results='html')

Username:  user
Password:  pwd
SAS Connection established.

%%SAS
options comamid=tcp;
let srvs = server2;
signon noscript remote=srvs user="&Sysuserid" password='pwd';

LIBNAME rwork slibref=work server=srvs;



NOTE: Libref RWORK was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        REMOTE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect SASPy can't see the remote as you say.  You can certainly find out by running code in SAS, just run this inside the rsubmit block:

```
%put %sysfunc(getoption(work));
```

So have python send that to SAS within an rsubmit block and you should get your result back in the log (or return it in some other format convenient to you).